# Can podman connect to a remote docker host by setting $DOCKER_HOST?

Tags: docker, podman

I know that podman is a daemonless container engine, which is a plus.
But if I need to start a container on a remote host running docker server, is this possible through podman?

e.g. Having placed the corresponding certificates into `~/.docker/` would the following run hello-world on the remote server, as `docker` command does?

```
export DOCKER_HOST=tcp://remote-docker-server:2376;
export DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY=1;
podman run hello-world
```

> [doc](https://podman.io/): [..]Simply put: `alias docker=podman`[..]

Since podman team proposes aliasing `docker` command to `podman`, I need to know whether I will still be able to use the `docker` command as before.

Comment: Please justify downvoting.

Comment: At the end of these [slides](https://dwalsh.fedorapeople.org/ReplacingDockerWithPodman.pdf), [@rhatdan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11081228/rhatdan) mentions that: *"Docker API - We have no plans to support this, but we do have Varlink"*. I've also bumped into something called `podman-remote` here:[podman-remote man page](https://www.mankier.com/1/podman-remote)

Comment: @tgogos I now saw that there is also a podman-remote client page at [podman repo](https://github.com/containers/libpod/blob/master/docs/tutorials/remote_client.md) using the ansible-style approach (via ssh) for remote tasks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Podman does not have any support for the Docker API. It cannot connect to Docker on either the local host or a remote host. If you need to start a container on a remote host, you can:

```
ssh remotehost podman run ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Docker and Podman are totally different beasts. Podman implements some docker api compatibility layer, thus by allowing docker clients to access Podman API - but it is only in such direction. There's no compatibility layer between Podman Clients and Docker API. Just use docker client to control docker.

However, if you use podman everywhere - you could control remote instances in a way:

`podman -r --url tcp://address to remove instance:port  <any command>`

Answer (score 1):

```
export DOCKER_HOST = "ssh://root@podman-romote-host"
podman system connection add --identity ~/.ssh/id_rsa production $DOCKER_HOST
podman run hello-world
```